# Logitech c920e -- v4l2-ctl --list-devices\ Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, manjaro, camera

just bought the logi c920e and unfortunately it does not appears to be working.

None of the other users questions have helped, most were related to a built in camm which is not my case. I have tested on Fedora, Linux Mint, Manjaro(current OS) and in none of them it appears to work.

tried a install of windows 10, worked.

! A litte bit more of info, be it on cheese, obs or vlc, the webcam does not show. Im still looking for more info, and as it goes i will be adding here.

**dmesg | tail**

```
dmesg | tail                  
[   82.553845] audit: type=1101 audit(1637396188.080:103): pid=2438 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="kaiqueam" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   82.554104] audit: type=1110 audit(1637396188.080:104): pid=2438 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   82.557650] audit: type=1105 audit(1637396188.083:105): pid=2438 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   82.565367] audit: type=1106 audit(1637396188.090:106): pid=2438 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   82.565459] audit: type=1104 audit(1637396188.090:107): pid=2438 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   94.652318] audit: type=1101 audit(1637396200.177:108): pid=2457 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=pam_unix,pam_permit,pam_time acct="kaiqueam" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   94.652622] audit: type=1110 audit(1637396200.177:109): pid=2457 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_env,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   94.656734] audit: type=1105 audit(1637396200.183:110): pid=2457 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_open grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   94.665469] audit: type=1106 audit(1637396200.190:111): pid=2457 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:session_close grantors=pam_limits,pam_unix,pam_permit acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
[   94.665608] audit: type=1104 audit(1637396200.190:112): pid=2457 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=2 subj==unconfined msg='op=PAM:setcred grantors=pam_faillock,pam_permit,pam_env,pam_faillock acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/2 res=success'
```

**v4l2-ctl --list-devices**

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices                                 
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

```
v4l2-ctl --all 
Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.
```

**sudo dmesg | grep -i camera -> returns nothing**

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i camera
```

**lsusb**

```
lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1462:7b85 Micro Star International PRO CARBON   
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 046d:083f Logitech, Inc. USB VSNx      
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 05ac:024f Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2/50
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lspci**

```
❯ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01)
03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01)
03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01)
20:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
20:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
20:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
21:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
22:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 [GeForce RTX 2060] (rev a1)
26:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 HD Audio Controller (rev a1)
26:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
26:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU104 USB Type-C UCSI Controller (rev a1)
27:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
27:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
27:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin USB 3.0 Host controller
28:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
28:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
28:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

**lsmod**

```
❯ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 90112  16
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   32768  2
btusb                  69632  0
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
btbcm                  20480  1 btusb
btintel                32768  1 btusb
bluetooth             733184  43 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
ecc                    40960  1 ecdh_generic
hid_logitech_hidpp     53248  0
joydev                 28672  0
mousedev               24576  0
hid_apple              16384  0
hid_logitech_dj        28672  0
uas                    32768  0
qrtr                   20480  4
ns                     36864  1 qrtr
iwlmvm                495616  0
usb_storage            81920  2 uas
usbhid                 65536  1 hid_logitech_dj
apple_mfi_fastcharge    20480  0
mac80211             1171456  1 iwlmvm
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
iwlwifi               430080  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211             1044480  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
igb                   266240  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 igb
rfkill                 32768  9 bluetooth,cfg80211
dca                    16384  1 igb
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
uinput                 20480  0
squashfs               69632  8
intel_rapl_common      28672  1 intel_rapl_msr
nvidia_drm             73728  9
edac_mce_amd           32768  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   155648  1
nvidia_modeset       1155072  24 nvidia_drm
kvm_amd               139264  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
ccp                   118784  1 kvm_amd
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
ucsi_ccg               24576  0
typec_ucsi             49152  1 ucsi_ccg
rng_core               16384  1 ccp
snd_hda_intel          57344  5
typec                  65536  1 typec_ucsi
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
kvm                  1036288  1 kvm_amd
nvidia              36958208  1376 nvidia_modeset
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         176128  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
vfat                   24576  1
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
roles                  16384  1 typec_ucsi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
fat                    86016  1 vfat
snd_hda_core          110592  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
drm_kms_helper        294912  1 nvidia_drm
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
aesni_intel           380928  8
snd_pcm               147456  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
cec                    73728  1 drm_kms_helper
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 28672  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
rapl                   16384  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_timer              45056  1 snd_pcm
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd                   114688  18 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
pcspkr                 16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
sp5100_tco             20480  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
wmi                    36864  1 wmi_bmof
drm                   589824  13 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
mac_hid                16384  0
pinctrl_amd            32768  0
gpio_generic           20480  1 gpio_amdpt
acpi_cpufreq           32768  0
agpgart                45056  1 drm
loop                   40960  16
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler        73728  1 ipmi_devintf
sg                     40960  0
fuse                  167936  7
crypto_user            20480  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
ext4                  929792  2
crc32c_generic         16384  0
crc16                  16384  2 bluetooth,ext4
mbcache                16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  151552  1 ext4
crc32c_intel           24576  4
xhci_pci               20480  0
```

looking at obs, is there a chance linux thinks this is a mic?

[obs_image reference, maybe it thinks is a mic?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPjUy.png)

```
❯ lsmod|grep uvcvideo
uvcvideo              118784  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         36864  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       69632  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
videodev              282624  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
```

also tried reloading the module

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

still no device and no changes based on the prior logs above.

**
running:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

generates de video0 which was inexistent then

```
❯ v4l2-ctl --list-devices  
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
        /dev/video0
```

giving an LS inside dev/ note that before modprobe there was not any video0

```
❯ ls            
ashmem           hpet            nvme0      stdout  tty31  tty56   ttyS22        vcs3
autofs           hugepages       nvme0n1    tty     tty32  tty57   ttyS23        vcs4
block            hwrng           nvme0n1p1  tty0    tty33  tty58   ttyS24        vcs5
bsg              input           nvme0n1p2  tty1    tty34  tty59   ttyS25        vcs6
btrfs-control    kmsg            nvme0n1p3  tty10   tty35  tty6    ttyS26        vcsa
bus              kvm             nvram      tty11   tty36  tty60   ttyS27        vcsa1
char             lightnvm        port       tty12   tty37  tty61   ttyS28        vcsa2
console          log             ppp        tty13   tty38  tty62   ttyS29        vcsa3
core             loop0           pps0       tty14   tty39  tty63   ttyS3         vcsa4
cpu              loop1           psaux      tty15   tty4   tty7    ttyS30        vcsa5
cpu_dma_latency  loop2           ptmx       tty16   tty40  tty8    ttyS31        vcsa6
cuse             loop3           ptp0       tty17   tty41  tty9    ttyS4         vcsu
disk             loop4           pts        tty18   tty42  ttyS0   ttyS5         vcsu1
dma_heap         loop5           random     tty19   tty43  ttyS1   ttyS6         vcsu2
dri              loop6           rfkill     tty2    tty44  ttyS10  ttyS7         vcsu3
fb0              loop7           rtc        tty20   tty45  ttyS11  ttyS8         vcsu4
fd               loop8           rtc0       tty21   tty46  ttyS12  ttyS9         vcsu5
full             loop-control    sda        tty22   tty47  ttyS13  udmabuf       vcsu6
fuse             mapper          sda1       tty23   tty48  ttyS14  uhid          vfio
gpiochip0        mem             sdb        tty24   tty49  ttyS15  uinput        vga_arbiter
gpiochip1        mqueue          sg0        tty25   tty5   ttyS16  urandom       vhci
hidraw0          net             sg1        tty26   tty50  ttyS17  usb           vhost-net
hidraw1          ng0n1           shm        tty27   tty51  ttyS18  userio        vhost-vsock
hidraw2          null            snapshot   tty28   tty52  ttyS19  v4l2loopback  video0
hidraw3          nvidia0         snd        tty29   tty53  ttyS2   vcs           watchdog
hidraw4          nvidiactl       stderr     tty3    tty54  ttyS20  vcs1          watchdog0
hidraw5          nvidia-modeset  stdin      tty30   tty55  ttyS21  vcs2          zero
```

but there is no use to this. running :

```
❯ gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -c:v rawvideo -f v4l2 /dev/video0
ffmpeg version n4.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-amf --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-lto --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librav1e --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100

*** Error ***              
Could not detect any camera
*** Error (-105: 'Unknown model') ***       

pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: I had a similar issue on Pop!_OS 22.04, from `lsusb -v -d ...`, `idVendor: Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. WebCamera`, `iManufacturer:  XHT 105 201105`, `v4l2-ctl --list-devices` returning only `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.` Just a reboot and it was working, maybe adding my user to video group (`sudo adduser $USER video`) had something to do.

Answer (score 2):

Previously, the Logitech HD Pro C920 has had several different USB product IDs, like 082d, 0892 and 08e5, which probably indicates different versions of the camera's internals although the model number has been kept the same. Now your webcam has product ID 083f, which is not known at all to the Linux USB ID repository: https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/046d

Also the text displayed for it by `lsusb` is `Logitech, Inc. USB VSNx` which is a little odd.

Unfortunately it looks like the c920e might be a yet another new version that is not yet known to the `uvcvideo` driver. Or it might require firmware that needs to be sent to the camera by the OS after each reboot, before the camera will appear as a normal webcam device.

[This comparison of different Logitech C920 variants](https://www.streamtechreviews.com/blog/c920-variations) is written from the viewpoint of a Windows user, but seems to confirm that the C920e may have some technical differences compared to the older variants: e.g. the microphone being disabled by default.

The `uvcvideo` driver will actually connect to any device that claims to belong to the appropriate USB device class, but it also identifies specific cameras because some of them either cannot be detected using the generic method, or they have some quirks that need special handling.

Since the driver does not seem to detect your camera, it's possible the camera presents itself to the USB bus in some non-standard way that will need to be handled specially by the `uvcvideo` driver maintainers.

With my Logitech C922, if I run `lsusb -d 046d:085c -v |grep -e Class -e Config`, I'll get this output:

```
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
      bFunctionClass         14 Video
      bFunctionSubClass       3 Video Interface Collection
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Video Control
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bInterfaceClass        14 Video
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Video Streaming
      bFunctionClass          1 Audio
      bFunctionSubClass       2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Control Device
        wChannelConfig     0x0003
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
      bInterfaceClass         1 Audio
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 Streaming
  bDeviceClass          239 Miscellaneous Device
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bNumConfigurations      1
```

Note the presence of audio & video control interfaces, and a number of different stream interfaces for both audio & video.

If you run `lsusb -d 046d:083f -v | grep -e Class -e Config`, will you get anything similar?

If the `bNumConfigurations` has a value other than 1, the camera might need to be switched to an alternate USB configuration before it works as a camera.

(Some USB devices will initially present themselves as an USB storage device that contains Windows/Mac drivers for the device. The driver would then know to switch the device to an alternate configuration that would reveal the real device interface.)

Comment: thanks for the response, i was in the blink of insanity already, so... is there anything i can do?

Answer (score -2):

You can also just take the plug out and then plug it back in. Sometimes it works for me. Another thing I do is to close some of the things running in the back ground. i.e.

1. `ps aux | grep python3`
2. `sudo kill -9 <the id given besides the roots>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).